How the cardinalities of $\mathcal H^*_x$ and $\mathcal P(x)$ compare?
Working in $\sf ZF$, regarding an arbitrary Dedekind infinite set $x$, what's the relationship between the cardinality of $\mathcal P(x)$ and $\mathcal H^*_x$? The latter is the set of all sets hereditarily subnumerous to $x$, where subnumerous to means "is injective to" , by "$y$ is to hereditarily subnumerous to $x$" here it specifically  means every element of the transitive closure of $\{y\} $ is subnumerous to $x$. Transitive closure defined in the customary way as the minimal transitive superset.
Are there special constraints on how they compare given Choice, GCH, V=L, etc.. Can they be incomparable? I'm interested in cases where $\mathcal H^*_x$ is subnumerous to $\mathcal P(x)$, whether strictly or not, especially outside of choice?
Also how matters would differ if we defined $\mathcal H^*_x$ as the set of all sets whose transitive closure is subnumerous to $x$?  Especially as regards it being subnumerous to $\mathcal P(x) $ in absence of choice?

When $x$ is $\omega$, then $H_\omega$ is countably infinite, but $P(\omega)$ is strictly larger, even in ZF.

Wouldn't it be more natural to want to compare $H_\kappa$ with $P_\kappa(\kappa)$, which is the set of subsets of $\kappa$ of size less than $\kappa$. In ZFC+GCH, these have the same size for all infinite regular $\kappa$.

Another issue is that even in ZFC we don't define $H_\kappa$ as the collection of sets that are hereditarily of size less than $\kappa$, if what this means is that they have size less than $\kappa$, and their elements also, and the elements of those sets, etc. This gives the wrong result when $\kappa$ is singular. One normally defines $H_\kappa$ as the collection of sets whose transitive closures have size less than $\kappa$. I'm not sure what "subnumerous" means, but in the ZF context all talk of cardinality is more subtle and complicated, so it might help to say more exactly what is meant.

Sorry, you don't need GCH in my earlier comment. It is true in ZFC.

@JoelDavidHamkins, I've edited to clarify.

You say "every element of the transitive closure of ${y}$ is small", but this is exactly making the mistake I mentioned. The usual definition would say that the transitive closure itself is small.  Also, you are using $\leq$ instead of $<$, which means that if ZFC holds, your terminology does not match the established terminology. For example, your notation has no way to refer to the hereditarily finite sets.

@JoelDavidHamkins, Yes, but the question is about when $x$ is a Dedekind infinite. Also, I need the relation to be $\leq$ and not just $<$. As for the transitive closure definition being itself smaller, I've given this alternative to compare with the main alternative. I need some freedom in comparisons between the powersets and the hereditarily size sets, that's why I'm asking about both versions. I'll modify the notation a little bit as not to be confused with the ordinary one.
